# vim-latex 'cite' command not showing citation options in quickfix window

Tags: vim, vim-latex

The cite completion in vim-latex does not work on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04) for a specific document.

The document is a doctoral dissertation and involves multiple subdocuments that are imported into the higher-level parts of the document via subimport.

The idea from [1] to create a minimal reproducible example and test completion thereon was successful, however, only for the simple example.
How should I go forward get the cite autocompletion to work for the complex document?

Here is one other thing I have noticed: On the minimal example mentioned above, pressing F9 opened the quickfix window. 
In contrast, for the complex document, pressing F9 in a

```
\cite{}<++>
```

has no consequences at all. Maybe this information is useful in tracking down the problem?
Any help or hints are much appreciated!

[1]
[How to get vim-latex's \cite completion to work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26312/how-to-get-vim-latexs-cite-completion-to-work/26329#26329)

Comment: (1) Do you have a `latexmain` file? (2) What happens if you change instances of `subimport` to `input`? (3) What exactly do you mean by a "complex document"? A [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be helpful, e.g. does the problem persist if you have a very basic 'main' file that is used to `subimport` a (possibly empty?) file?

Comment: @Anthony: Thanks for helping to track this error down. The problem is _not_ reproducible when creating a mwe with subimport. I can access the bibtex entries from the subimported tex file.

Comment: Could it be that due to some compilation errors, vim-latex cannot access the bib file?

Comment: Have you tried making a copy of the complex document and removing as much text (including things in the preamble) as possible so that the problem persists? e.g. the issue could be in the preamble or an equation, figure, etc. It's impossible to know unless you isolate the problem.

Comment: @Anthony: For some reason, I can now access the bibliography via the F9 key. I am using '''\begin{comment} \bibliograph{../../05_bib/bibliography_diss}\end{comment}''' at the head of the corresponding sub-document, which is included via '''\subimport''' command. Thanks for your time!