# Vim-latexsuite bibliography completion does not work

Tags: vim-latex

I am using the following files:

**test.tex**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\begin{document}
\citet{s}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

and **test.bib**:

```
@article{six,
  title        = "The Six -- a Boring Number",
  author       = "Name, Alice and Other, Bob",
  journal      = "Journal for Testing Affairs",
  year         = 2066,
  volume       = 66,
  number       = 6,
  pages        = "66--666",
}
@article{seven,
  title        = "The Seven -- an Interesting Number",
  author       = "Name, Alice and Other, Bob",
  journal      = "Journal for Testing Affairs",
  year         = 2077,
  volume       = 77,
  number       = 7,
  pages        = "77--777",
}
```

With these I try the following to get the bibliography autocompletion of vim-latexsuite to work: I place the coursor behind the `s` in `\citet{s}` and press [F9].

According to the [manual](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-completion-cite.html) I should now get a new editor pane with content along the lines of

```
Article [six]
   "The Six -- a Boring Number"
   Alice Name and Bob Other
   In Journal for Testing Affairs, 2066

Article [seven]
   "The Seven -- an Interesting Number"
   Alice Name and Bob Other
   In Journal for Testing Affairs, 2077
```

Here I should be able to e.g. filter the items by author or year.

**Instead** I get two new editor panes.

The first titled **test.tex [+]** containing

```
test.bib|1 col 1| @article{six,
test.bib|10 col 1| @article{seven,
```

what appears to be some sort of grep results.

The second editor panes is titled **[QuickFix-Liste] :grep.exe -nH ____HIGHLY_IMPROBABLE____ test.tex** and contains the contents of the file `test.bib`.

No filtering is possible and not the other navigation methods named in the manual.

**How do I set up the citation completion properly?**

I believe vim-latexsuite is set up correctly (i.e. I see the TeX-relatex menu items). I am working with gvim80 unter Windows 10, I have installed python 2.7 and GNU grep, both are in the path. The vimrc contains the line `set grepprg=grep.exe\ -nH\ $*` as advised in the manual.

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198016/vim-latex-cite-command-not-showing-citation-options-in-quickfix-window

Comment: also related (and probably the same problem): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26312/how-to-get-vim-latexs-cite-completion-to-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this on the [issues](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/issues/113) at the vim-latex github repository and got the following help:

The Problem was that my python was not working. I could easily identify this by typing

```
:echo has('python')
:echo has('python3')
```

in vim where both resulted in `0`, i.e. no python activated.

When I typed `:python print("Hello World")` I got an error saying that `python27.dll` could not be loaded what brought me to [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/322138/vim-could-not-load-library-python27-dll#747043). There I found that **a 32bit vim is not compatible with a 64bit python** or vice versa.